# Hide columns with specific names in datagrip

Tags: datagrip

How would I go about hiding columns with a specific names? I have tables in my database with a few audit fields always named the same thing in each table:

```
created_at
updated_at
created_by
updated_by
```

This is an annoyance to the application developers who only wish to see the fields relevent to them. Is there a setting I can change to not show this on every table in the database sidebar? [image: audit fields]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, now it's impossible in DataGrip :(
Please, comment and follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1387